# react-native How can I put two texts in a row view with left alignment?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to implement a View with two texts with different styles on it. I have this:

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
  <Text style={styles.style1}>
    {text1}
  </Text>

  <Text style={styles.style2}>
    {text2}
   </Text>
</View>
```

Which shows something like:
[This is my actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir8xX.png)
But I want to achive this: 
[My desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfkVW.png)

Comment: Can you also include your stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wrap them with a Text component instead of View, it should work:

```
<Text>
  <Text style={styles.style1}>
    {text1}
  </Text>

  <Text style={styles.style2}>
    {text2}
   </Text>
</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Text>
  <Text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>Description: </Text>
  This is an example of the text flow I want to achieve.
</Text>
```

[Live demo](https://snack.expo.io/ryyh3Koxf)